# Port forwarding Router

Tags: windows-10

Let me briefly explain the problem, I live in a building where the owner provides the internet.

In my project I have to use a port forwarding to connect to my computer. The owner won't let me use port forwarding for security reasons.

I have two questions:

if I install SoftEther VPN do I still need access to port forwarding?
Is it possible to solve this problem or can I use it only locally?

Comment: If a VPN can be established, other hosts in the VPN can "connect to your computer" with its VPN IP without needing you to "port forward", as they are traversing the NAT through the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Do you have access to some box you can SSH to that is not behind a NAT? This would be sufficient to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

VPN can be used to connect a client to a VPN server, but cannot be used to
connect two clients (in the general case for free services).

For connecting two computers, both presumably behind NAT routers,
you need another kind of connection between the two computers that is
based on
[Tunneling protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol).
For a detailed explanation of how tunnelling services work, see this
[Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596901/how-tunneling-services-like-localtunnel-works-without-ssh/52614266#52614266).

Below are listed some free services for tunneling:

- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
- [Serveo](https://serveo.net/)
- [Localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/)
- [localhost.run](http://localhost.run/)
- [Telebit](https://telebit.cloud/)
- [beame-insta-ssl](https://github.com/beameio/beame-insta-ssl/)

For helping decide between them, see their reviews in the article
[Tunnelling services for exposing localhost to the web](https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/tunnelling-services-for-exposing-localhost-to-the-web/).